# Pig: Unable to load data using PigStorage

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig, bigdata

I have this smaple dataset in a txt file (Format: Firstname,Lastname,age,gender)

```
(Eric,Ack,27,M),(Jeremy,Ross,29,F)
(Jenny,Dicken,27,F),(Vijay,Sampath,40,M)
(Angs,Dicken,28,M),(Venu,Rao,28,M)
(Mahima,Mohanty,29,F),(Kenny,Oath,28,M)
```

I am trying to load this data like this:

```
tuple_record = LOAD '~/Documents/Pig_Tuple.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (details:tuple(firstname:chararray,lastname:chararray,age:int,sex:chararray));
```

But this is not working:

```
DUMP tuple_record;
```

I got this when running this command (i.e. It returns nothing)

```
()
()
()
()
```

Please advice how to load this dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is, both the `tuple` and `each fields` inside the tuple have the `same delimiter`(`','`).  In this case, pig will parse the input and failed in the schema conversion.

You can see the below logs in your console

```
"Unable to interpret the value in field being converted to type tuple, caught ParseException <Unexpect end of tuple> field discarded"
```

**To fix this issue**

1. You need to change the tuple delimiter `','`  to something different. In the below example i have used `'#'` as delimiter instead of `','`. You can use any delimiter other than (',')
2. Your input file have two tuples but you defined only one tuple in the load schema, so you need to define the other one also.

**Sample example:**

**input**

```
(Eric,Ack,27,M)#(Jeremy,Ross,29,F)
(Jenny,Dicken,27,F)#(Vijay,Sampath,40,M)
(Angs,Dicken,28,M)#(Venu,Rao,28,M)
(Mahima,Mohanty,29,F)#(Kenny,Oath,28,M)
```

**Pigscript:**

```
tuple_record = LOAD '~/Documents/Pig_Tuple.txt' USING PigStorage('#') AS (details:tuple(firstname:chararray,lastname:chararray,age:int,sex:chararray), details1:tuple(firstname1:chararray,lastname1:chararray,age1:int,sex1:chararray));
DUMP tuple_record;
```

**output:**

```
((Eric,Ack,27,M),(Jeremy,Ross,29,F))
((Jenny,Dicken,27,F),(Vijay,Sampath,40,M))
((Angs,Dicken,28,M),(Venu,Rao,28,M))
((Mahima,Mohanty,29,F),(Kenny,Oath,28,M))
```

**Update:**
**How to change the delimiter ',' to something different**
**Option1: Using sed**
This is very easy option, by using sed command replace the `'),('` pattern to `')#('` pattern, so that the delimiter will be changed from `','` to `'#'` in the same input file.(Note:take backup of your input file before executing this sed script)

```
>> sed -i -- 's/),(/)#(/g' inputFile
```

**Option2: Slight modification in the pigscript without changing the delimiter**
**Pigscript:**

```
--Read each input line as chararray
A = LOAD 'inputFile' AS (line:chararray);

--Remove the character '(',')' from the input
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(REPLACE(line,'[)(]+','')) AS (newline:chararray);

--Split the input using ',' as delimiter, 8 refer to total number of fields
C = FOREACH B GENERATE FLATTEN(STRSPLIT(newline,',',8)) AS (firstname1:chararray,lastname1:chararray,age1:int,sex1:chararray,firstname2:chararray,lastname2:chararray,age2:int,sex2:chararray);

--Group the fields and form tuples 
D = FOREACH C GENERATE TOTUPLE(firstname1,lastname1,age1,sex1) AS details1,TOTUPLE(firstname2,lastname2,age2,sex2) AS details2;

--Now you can do whatever you want.
E = FOREACH D GENERATE details1.firstname1,details2.firstname2;
DUMP E;
```

Comment: Any suggestions how to change the delimiters of the input files? Please suggest

Comment: One option could be you can use STORE command to change the delimiter format. http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.13.0/basic.html#store.  Let me know if you need any help.

Comment: In the example, the data is loaded first and then stored with changed delimiter; but in my case the loading itself is causing a problem. Please help.

Comment: Ok got it. I have updated two solutions in the post. please check it.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the complex scheme section of the [Pig Documentation](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/basic.html#schema-complex)

```
cat data;
(3,8,9) (mary,19)
(1,4,7) (john,18)
(2,5,8) (joe,18)

A = LOAD data AS (F:tuple(f1:int,f2:int,f3:int),T:tuple(t1:chararray,t2:int));

DESCRIBE A;
A: {F: (f1: int,f2: int,f3: int),T: (t1: chararray,t2: int)}

DUMP A;
((3,8,9),(mary,19))
((1,4,7),(john,18))
((2,5,8),(joe,18))
```